# Filling csv with "missing" rows

Tags: java, csv

I made a program which outputs a csv file like this:

```
9,rule
18,dont
19,Ive
19,advice
19,foundations
26,Sigh
29,nothing
29,nothing
33,name
```

I want to do 2 things:

First, I want to create a new csv which fills the "missing" rows in the first one. This means for example adding 8 lines before `9,rule` which should look like this:

```
1,no value
2,no value
3,no value
4,no value
5,no value
6,no value
7,no value
8,no value
```

Then you should have `9,rule` followed by another 8 "no value" lines before `18,dont`.

Also, as you can see, sometimes there are two or more values with the same numeric id, e.g. lines with 19. I want just the first one of them.

Unfortunately I couldn't came up with any working solution.

I'm using CommonsCSV to read the file, so a good start is this:

```
    Reader in = new FileReader("path-to-csv-file");
    Iterable<CSVRecord> records = CSVFormat.RFC4180.parse(in);

    String id = new String(); 
    String target = new String(); 

    for (CSVRecord record : records) {

        id = record.get(0); // gets the id
        target = record.get(1); // gets the string after ,

       // WHAT NOW???
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm stuck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
int prevId = 0;
for (CSVRecord record : records) {
    id = record.get(0);
    target = record.get(1);
    if(id == preId+1){
        System.out.println(id + " " + target);
        prevId = id;
    }else if(id > prevId+1){
        prevId++;
        for(; prevId < id; prevId++){
            System.out.println(prevId + " no target");
        }
        System.out.println(id + " " + target);
        prevId = id;
    }
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you very much and have a nice day :)

Comment: @NoobNe0 Great, I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Use a variable to work as a counter variable, printing the value if id matches, else printing all the values till we reach id equivalent.

```
int _id = 1;

    for (CSVRecord record : records) {

        id = record.get(0);
        target = record.get(1);

        while (_id != id) {
          // Print _id,no value
          _id++;
        }
        // Print _id,target
        _id++;
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately I think there's something wrong because it loops indefinetely

Comment: Forgot to increment it the`if` block. Fixed it.

Comment: That wasn't the issue.. I'm still getting 

1;no target
2;no target
3;no target
4;no target
5;no target
6;no target
7;no target
8;no target
9;no target
10;no target
11;no target
12;no target
13;no target

Comment: Check with this modified logic.

Comment: No luck even with this unfortunately. Anyway I solved it thanks toTitus. Thank you anyway for your interest.